# SAS proc means throws an error trying to read a data set Work.X

Tags: sql, statistics, sas

I am trying to Imput the three missing values for q2 by the mean of the entire column Here is all of the relevant code used in the program

```
libname surveym "\\vdi-fileshare01\UEMprofiles\029946759\Desktop";
libname apis "\\vdi-fileshare01\UEMprofiles\029946759\Desktop";
data survey;
set surveym.surveyresults;
run;
data api;
set apis.api;
run;
proc sort data=survey;
by SchoolName;
run;
proc sort data=api;
by SchoolName;
run;
data schools;
merge api survey;
by SchoolName;
if q1='.' 
then delete;
run;
proc means data=schools
var q2;
output out=stats mean=q2_mean;
run;
data _null_;
set stats;
call symput('mean_q2',q2_mean);
run;
```

However here is the log output that occurs that confuses me.

```
 var q2;
         --
         22
         202
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ALPHA, CHARTYPE, CLASSDATA, CLM,
```

as well as

```
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
552  output out=stats mean=q2_mean;
553  run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.STATS may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0
         observations and 0 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.STATS was not replaced because this step was stopped.
```

Im not sure whats causing this issue as I triple checked spelling and semi-colon placements.

***Also very sorry about formatting in the code on Stack-overflow the spacing didnt transfer over correctly***

Comment: The `Proc MEANS` statement is missing a terminating semi-colon (`;`). Thus the SAS parser thinks you are trying to use `VAR` as a proc option.